# MongoDB aggregate - match using lte and fallback to gte

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection with a structure (simplified) like this:

```
[
  {
    "name" : "name1",
    "instances" : [ 
      {
        "value" : 1,
        "score" : 2,
        "date" : ISODate("2015-03-04T00:00:00.000Z")
      }, 
      {
        "value" : 2,
        "score" : 5,
        "date" : ISODate("2015-04-01T00:00:00.000Z")
      }, 
      {
        "value" : 2.5,
        "score" : 9,
        "date" : ISODate("2015-03-05T00:00:00.000Z")
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name" : "name2",
    "instances" : [ 
      {
        "value" : 6,
        "score" : 3,
        "date" : ISODate("2015-03-05T00:00:00.000Z")
      }, 
      {
        "value" : 1,
        "score" : 6,
        "date" : ISODate("2015-03-04T00:00:00.000Z")
      }, 
      {
        "value" : 3.7,
        "score" : 5.2,
        "date" : ISODate("2015-02-04T00:00:00.000Z")
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name" : "name3",
    "instances" : [ 
      {
        "value" : 6,
        "score" : 3,
        "date" : ISODate("2015-03-05T00:00:00.000Z")
      }, 
      {
        "value" : 1,
        "score" : 6,
        "date" : ISODate("2015-03-04T00:00:00.000Z")
      }, 
      {
        "value" : 3.7,
        "score" : 5.2,
        "date" : ISODate("2015-02-04T00:00:00.000Z")
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Currently I have an `aggregate` query that pulls a single instance from each document by a given date:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$instances"},      
  {$sort: {'instances.date': -1}},
  {$match: {'instances.date': {$lte: <givenDate>}}},
  {$project: {name: 1, _id: 0, date: "$instances.date", value: "$instances.value", score: "$instances.score"}},
  {$group: {_id: "$name", name: {$first: "$name"}, date: {$first: "$date"},
    value: {$first: "$value"}, score: {$first: "$score"}}}
])
```

This query works just fine, and for a given date will return the latest (that is, exactly or before the given date) instance from every document.

My problem begins when the given date is prior to the earliest instance. For example, if my given date is 2015-03-02, I will not get any instance from `name1`. In that case, I want to retrieve the earliest instance available in the document.

Obviously, I can split this task into two different queries and merge the results, but I would like to achieve this goal in a single DB query if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: In that case why do you need to specify the `date` at all?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. I'm getting the date from user selection, and I need to get the most recent values up to that date. In the case where the date is too early for some items, I want to get the earliest one.

Comment: I mean the following. The specified `date` does not make sense if you have that condition. In other words, no matter if you specify the `date`, your result for each document is going to be the `$first` date. Am I missing something?

Comment: In the example DB above, if the `date` is 2015-03-04, then the result set will contain the first instance from `name1`, the second instance from `name2`, and the second from `name3`. If the `date` is 2015-03-02, then result set will contain just 2 items (the third instance from both `name2` and `name3`). In that case I will want to add to that result set the earliest (in this case - the first) instance from `name1`

Comment: Ok, I think now I got it. So you want the dates that are earlier and **closest** to the date you specified. But if there is no such date for a document, include the earliest date (*the date that is the furthest from NOW*)?

Comment: The only case that will happen is when there are no instances at all for that document

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78933/discussion-between-n9code-and-yarons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Pipeline**

Try this pipeline, and then let's go step-by-step:

```
[
   {$unwind: "$instances"},
   {$project: {
                 _id: 0, 
                 name: 1, 
                 date: '$instances.date', 
                 matches: {
                             $cond: [
                                       {$lte: ['$instances.date', new Date(<YOUR DATE>)]}, 
                                       1, 
                                       0
                             ]
                 }, 
                 score: '$instances.score', 
                 value: '$instances.value'
              }
   }, 
   {$group: {
                 _id: '$name', 
                 instances: {
                               $push: {
                                         date: '$date', 
                                         score: '$score', 
                                         value: '$value', 
                                         matches: '$matches'
                               }
                 }, 
                 hasMatches: {$sum: '$matches'}
            }
   }, 
   {$unwind: "$instances"}, 
   {$project: {
                 _id: 0, 
                 name: '$_id', 
                 date: '$instances.date', 
                 hasMatches: '$hasMatches', 
                 matches: '$instances.matches', 
                 score: '$instances.score', 
                 value: '$instances.value'
              }
   }, 
   {$sort: {'name': 1, 'matches': -1, 'date': -1}}, 
   {$group: {
                 _id: {name: '$name', hasMatches: '$hasMatches'}, 
                 last_date: {$last: '$date'}, 
                 last_score: {$last: '$score'}, 
                 last_value: {$last: '$value'}, 
                 first_date: {$first: '$date'}, 
                 first_score: {$first: '$score'}, 
                 first_value: {$first: '$value'}}
   }, 
   {$project: {
                 name: '$_id.name', 
                 date: {$cond: ['$_id.hasMatches', '$first_date', '$last_date']}, 
                 score: {$cond: ['$_id.hasMatches', '$first_score', '$last_score']}, 
                 value: {$cond: ['$_id.hasMatches', '$first_value', '$last_value']}, 
                 _id: 0}
   }
]
```

**The Explanation**

The first `$unwind` and `$project` stages are simple and obvious, I only added a `matches` field which indicates whether the unwounded document matches your criteria.

Then we `$group` back the documents, and at the same time `$sum` up the `matches` field into the new `hasMatches`. The resulting documents now contain `hasMatches` field which indicates whether the `instances` array contains at least one element that matches your criteria.

Then again, we `$unwind` and `$project`, and afterwards `$group` again, keeping the `hasMatches` field and storing both `$first` and `$last` values for `date`, `value` and `score` for further processing.

Now the situation is as follows:

- If there was at least one element in the initial array, that matched the criteria, in the result of sorting it has appeared as the *first* document in its group.
- If there was **no** element in the initial array that matched the criteria, then in the result of sorting, the element with the earliest date appeared as the *last* document in its group.

So, as we have the `hasMatches` field which indicates the above condition, as well as both `first_X` and `last_X` values, we can easily pick one of those, depending on the `hasMatches` value. Thus the last `$project` stage, which does exactly that.

**The Results**

Here are the results for the dates you have mentioned in the comments:

*'2015-03-04'*:

```
{ "name" : "name3", "date" : ISODate("2015-03-04T00:00:00Z"), "score" : 6, "value" : 1 }
{ "name" : "name2", "date" : ISODate("2015-03-04T00:00:00Z"), "score" : 6, "value" : 1 }
{ "name" : "name1", "date" : ISODate("2015-03-04T00:00:00Z"), "score" : 2, "value" : 1 }
```

*'2015-03-02'*:

```
{ "name" : "name3", "date" : ISODate("2015-02-04T00:00:00Z"), "score" : 5.2, "value" : 3.7 }
{ "name" : "name2", "date" : ISODate("2015-02-04T00:00:00Z"), "score" : 5.2, "value" : 3.7 }
{ "name" : "name1", "date" : ISODate("2015-03-04T00:00:00Z"), "score" : 2, "value" : 1 }
```