# Database query with Optional filtering and prioritisation

Tags: database, mongodb, filter

I have a use case where there is a base entity and it is overridden based on some params. Where overrides are not present I would want to fall back to most matching Entity.

For example

```
{
  "id": "uuid1",
   "key": "welcome",
  "meta": {
    "abParam": "v1"
  },
  "Entity": {
    "Text": "hello"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "id": "uuid2",
  "key": "welcome",
  "meta": {
    "abParam": "v2"
  },
  "Entity": {
    "Text": "hi"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "id": "uuid3",
  "key": "welcome",
  "meta": {
    "abParam": "v2",
    "userType": "new"
  },
  "Entity": {
    "Text": "hi"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "id": "uuid4",
  "key": "welcome",
  "meta": {
  },
  "Entity": {
    "Text": "hi"
  }
}
```

These are the queries i want to may, and the result i am expecting

| Query | Response | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| key=welcome, meta.abParam:v2 | uuid2 | match the most matching document |
| key=welcome, meta.abParam:v3 | uuid4 | fallback to default, if does not match |
| key=welcome, meta.abParam:v2, meta.userType: new | uuid3 | since there are 2 filter matches |

I know that elastic search can support this with weight function, but

1. is it possible to model this in other databases like Mongo, Mysql, Hbase, Couchbase? (If the database does not support this query  i will have to build the prioritisation logic in application layer, which is tougher to scale, considering I will have to transfer lot of data from DB to application layer and then apply filter.)
2. What other options are there to support this use case

Answer (score 0):

Upon researching here is what I found, The concept is shown in one db, but it can easily be applied to other databases,

**Storing All the combination in the document, and indexing on the field.**

let's say that there are n number of attributes on which we want to filter,   i.e. abParam, userType, etc, and there are m possible values for each field, i.e. v1,v2, v3 for abParam and post2016 ,post2017 for userType. We will store all the applied combination for a user in a field. Below is how a sample document will look like

```
 {
   "id": "uuid3",
   "key": "welcome",
   "userType": ["v2:post2016","v3:post2016"],
   "Entity": {
     "Text": "hi"
   }
 }
```

And we will index the userType field. Whenever we have to query we will query with id and userType.

Pros:

1. we can save on space occupied by not duplicating the documents

Cons:

1. All the possible combinations has to be known before hand. And needs to be ingested in document.
   This con can be mitigated, by having support for fallback query. For example search for `v2:post2016:hi` and if not found then `v2:post2016`. This can be done by using pipeline feature, where if nothing was found in for `v2:post2016:hi`, db will query for `v2:post2016`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30477196/mongodb-aggregate-match-using-lte-and-fallback-to-gte) is an example.

This solution can be implemented in other datastores as well, where ever secondary indexing on list is allowed.  [Mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/) and [Aerospike](https://docs.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-list-index-and-query.html) supports indexing on array fields.